# How to change state to a menu item?

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation

I need to change the status to active for each menu item when selected.

I'm using this:

```js
function() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        $(".menu a.drop").each(function() {
            if (url == (this.href)) {
                $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
```

It works, but the "href" attribute of the first item does not match the url.
Therefore, the first item does not take the class "active".

How I can make the first item takes the class active?

Comment: What have you found from debugging?  Is the `href` attribute of the anchor tag exactly equal to the window url?

Comment: Well, that explains why `if (url == (this.href)) {` doesn't work, right?